# "L'homme est un animal très spécial" - meaning of this sentence confuses a lot!

Tags: traduction, locutions

What is the meaning of this sentence? I am a bit confused by seeing the answer in google Translate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation in Google Translate is "Man is a very special animal", and it is accurate. The meaning is clear: it reflects the unbiased, unreligious—we might say "scientific"—point of view that this species, man, is nothing else than another one in the animal kingdom, but that it must be reckoned with that it is endowed with exceptional qualities (one tends to forget the exceptional ills of the species in the present context); this particularity of the animal is to be read in the words "très spécial", of course.

Comment: Ah, that's cool! I got it. Thank you!